# List of external schemas and tables from Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have created external schema and external table in Redshift. I'm able to see external schema name in postgresql using \dn.

What will be query to do it so that i can run it in java? and also the query to get list of external table?

I tried

```
select * from information_schema.tables where 
table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
and table_schema not like 'pg_toast%'
```

but it didn't get the list of external tables.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Redshift Spectrum external databases, schemas, and tables have their own catalog views.

- [SVV_EXTERNAL_DATABASES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_EXTERNAL_DATABASES.html)
- [SVV_EXTERNAL_SCHEMAS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_EXTERNAL_SCHEMAS.html)
- [SVV_EXTERNAL_TABLES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_EXTERNAL_TABLES.html)
- [SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS.html)
- [SVV_EXTERNAL_COLUMNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_EXTERNAL_COLUMNS.html)

You can query these from any connection: `SELECT * FROM svv_external_schemas;`